# update ng-if when hasClass value changes

Tags: jquery, forms, angularjs

I am using ng-if to hide/show an error message for a form validation. I basically want the error message to appear when the user has typed something in the URL field but this something is not recognized as a URL.

What I did so far is:

```
<input id="input-target-url" type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a URL here" required autofocus/>
<span ng-if="$('#input-target-url').hasClass('ng-invalid')">
  <i></i>
  <b>Please enter a valid URL</b>
</span>
```

My problem here is that the condition doesnt update when its value changes. So my span is always hidden.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, use the `.$invalid` property that Angular provides on your input element (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form).

Giving your input the name of `myInput` and assuming your form is `myForm`:

```
<input id="input-target-url" name="myInput" type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a URL here" required autofocus/>
<span ng-if="myForm.myInput.$invalid">
  <i></i>
  <b>Please enter a valid URL</b>
</span>
```

As noted in the comments, an empty string is an invalid URL, so the span will show even if the user hasn't inputted anything.  Fortunately, there's *another* property Angular gives us: `$dirty`.  This tells us if the user had edited the form element, and can be combined with the above to form:

```
<input id="input-target-url" name="myInput" type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a URL here" required autofocus/>
<span ng-if="myForm.myInput.$invalid && myForm.myInput.$dirty">
  <i></i>
  <b>Please enter a valid URL</b>
</span>
```

Comment: my field is invalid as long as the user hasnt typed any correct url so doing this the span is visible right from the start. How can I add the condition "!myForm.myInput:focus"?

Comment: the ng-dirty class is added as soon as the focus is on the input field so it is not enough, I need to show the message when the user has finished typing and its input is wrong, hence the :focus condition

Comment: This is beginning to feel less like a SO question and more like a requirements list.  How's about you Google a bit?